# Pandas read csv is shifting columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to create a dataframe of a csv file that has 4 empty columns. When I open it on LibreOffice or Excel it correctly identifies the empty columns. However, opening with `pd.read_csv()` ends up shifting the columns' values by one.

How can I solve this? It seems like a problem with pandas `read_csv()` method.

My code is really standard:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.read_csv('csv_file.csv', sep=',')
df.head()
```

I changed the headers and used this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.read_csv('csv_file.csv', sep=',', index_col=False).
```

This solved the problem, but what in my previous headers was causing this?

Comment: please give the csv file. If it too big, you can upload gist.github.com and post a link.

Comment: Try this: `df = pd.DataFrame.read_csv('csv_file.csv', sep=',', index_col=0)`

Comment: Did not work. Still shifting.

Answer (score 19):

It seems you need the parameter `index_col=False` to NOT read the first column to index in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), `sep=','` parameter can be omitted, because it is the default value:

```
df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv', index_col=False)
```

Your sample:

```
df = pd.read_csv('teste2.csv', index_col=False)
print (df)
  Header1 Header2  Header3  Unnamed: 3  Unnamed: 4  Header4  Header5  Header6  \
0     ptn  M00001        0         NaN         NaN        2        0        0   

   Header7  Header8    ...     Header22  Header23  Header24  Header25  \
0        0  -31.573    ...       -0.375       0.0   -64.168   276.586   

   Header26  Header27  Unnamed: 29  Unnamed: 30  Header28  Header29  
0    -0.232       0.0          NaN          NaN     0.702       1.0  

[1 rows x 33 columns]
```

Comment: Neither worked. I've no idea what is going on. I can see the empty columns when the csv is opened with gedit. What pandas is doing is a mystery.

Comment: I test it now and it works perfectly. So it seems some data problem. If you want, send me your file to my email in my profile, I can check it. Also what is your pandas version? `print (pd.show_versions())` ?

Comment: pandas: 0.19.0. I'll send a modified version of the file. IP problem.

Comment: Just sent you the file

Comment: Thank you. index_col=False for me working, for you not?

Comment: Oh, I just realized. it worked with the file i sent you. However, when i tried with my original file it didn't!.

Comment: I tried to use my original headers and the problem happened again on the file i sent you. I think there is some odd about these headers

Comment: Hmmm, so you dont get output like me in answer? It is pandas version related problem?

Comment: Not with my original headers.

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I use `pandas: 0.20.2`

Comment: I just update to `0.20.3` and there it works nice too.

Comment: Same here. I updated and your solution works fine with the file I sent you. But still no effect on the original file.

Comment: It seems in original data some columns names are missing, I guess only, because no data (maybe sensitive data)

Comment: 'when the csv has delimiters at the end of the each line' - it becomes a malformed csv file.

index_col=False solves that problem.

read more at - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem.  Here is how I have solved it:

1. Opened excel file with google spreadsheet on google drive
2. Downloaded spread sheet as `csv` file
3. Read the csv file via `pandas.read_csv('filename', sep=',', index_col=False))`

Problem resolved.

Comment: This is the true answer

Answer (score 5):

The problems occurs if your line ends with an delimiter (here comma[,]), which creates an empty cell generally not visible in MS Excel.
If your csv line looks like this:

```
1,2282816,102.97245065789474,2432,0.8333333333333334,0.1388888888888889,certain,
```

then modify it to:

```
1,2282816,102.97245065789474,2432,0.8333333333333334,0.1388888888888889,certain
```

and `pd.read_csv(fileName)` will work fine.

Comment: That turned out to be the problem for me when trying to load transactions from a download from Chase bank in CSV format. Striping the trailing comma from each data row solved it. Thanks. :)

Comment: For me as well. Wasted hours thinking that it was because of one column that was  ,, (empty) when in fact was due to the trailing comma at the end. What a lifesaver SamanwaySahoo! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Try writing headers on top of each column if there are none. This time, `read_csv()` also reads the headers and lists them.
After that convert the dataframe to an array by

```
df=df.values
```

and the headers are gone.